# Display a Sequence of Numbers in Android TextView

Tags: java, android, random, textview

I'm looking to display a sequence of numbers in a TextView field I created, but only one number is displayed once the method is called. How do I fix it to display all the numbers?

For example:

```
Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sequence);
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        Numbers[i] = random.nextInt(10)+1;              
        Display.setText(Numbers[i]+" ");        
    }
```

My guess is that it *is* displaying all the numbers, but only the last one with a space after it is shown. Anyway, I want all 10 numbers to appear on the same line. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Display.setText(Display.getText() + " " + Numbers[i]);
```

It might throw NullPointerException because first time there will be nothing to fetch for Display.getText();
So add `Display.setText(""); before loop.`

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! The exception hasn't appeared yet, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `setText()` once, after you have the complete string. This should work:

```
Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sequence);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    Numbers[i] = random.nextInt(10)+1;
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(Numbers[i]);
}
Display.setText(sb.toString());
```